# Free image viewer with folder tracking to display latest image automatically

Tags: windows, image-viewer

I'm looking for an image viewer for Windows which always displays a full-screen view of the newest image a specific folder. Preferably with raw image format support (Nikon) and free or inexpensive (< 20 Euros).

[FastPictureViewer](http://www.fastpictureviewer.com/) works very well, but since I only need this one feature, the price is a bit too high (49,99 USD).

The use case: I'm shooting product photos with a Nikon D50 in USB PTP (picture transfer protocol) mode, directly connected to a Intel NUC computer connected to a TV. Seeing the latest image automatically on the screen directly after shooting makes it very easy to adjust the lights and camera settings.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily monitor a given directory for new files using [python](http://python.org), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes-using-python) for 20+ answers, [rawpy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rawpy) can convert almost any cameras raw format to an 8 bit RGB array *in 3 lines of code*, then you have a choice of possible ways to display the image and lots of online help.  You could display the image for your self from within python or you can write your converted file to a fixed name tiff & use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) to display it with [automatic updating](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#update).

If you opt to display it within the python you could even use [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) to display the image with the histogram along side or as an overlay.

- Free, Gratis & Open Source,
- Cross Platform - will work on Windows, Mac OS-X or Linux *you don't mention which you need*,
- You can tailor the conversion to match your display,
- You can get it to do exactly what **you** decide you need.

Answer (score 2):

[IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/) has an hotfolder function that allows you to do this and is freeware.

See `Options` menu > `Hotfolder (watch folder)...`

Answer (score 0):

Irfanview hotfolder fn as mentioned above

Honeyview does not automatically show new files added to a folder in which a file is already opened but automatically re-scans the current folder so that new files added to that folder can be accessed without having to close and reopen Honeyview which is exactly what is necessary for other image viewing software - sometimes this is exactly what you want!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).